# Accessing functions which have been placed in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to have the user answer a few basic arithmetic questions.
I have defined a function (def) for each of Addition, Subtraction, Division but how can i get my program to randomly select on of them each time?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import random
from random import shuffle

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
rand1=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand2=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand3=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand4=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand5=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand6=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)

def Add():
    print("What is", rand1,"+",rand2,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand1+rand2:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")


def Sub():
    print("What is", rand3,"-",rand4,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand3-rand4:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")


def Div():
    print("What is", rand5,"/",rand6,"?")
    user=float(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == float("{0:.1f}".format(rand5/rand6)):
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")       


name = input("Hi. What is your name?\n")
print("Hello",name)



ADD=Add()
SUB=Sub()
DIV=Div()


Arith=[ADD,SUB,DIV]

x=1
while x<=10:
    print(random.choice(Arith))
    x+=1
```

Comment: Err... because you have a `break` there, so the loop only runs once? Anyway... what is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: Hi. 

Ignore the break. (I took it out)

I can't get the program to randomly pick among those 3 functions every time.
It goes through all three of them, in the order I have them in the list and then prints none 10 times.

Comment: @Faiakes What you get when you have python execute your code?  and, please, in which way it is different from what you expected?

Comment: @gboffi

This is what I get:
---------
Hi. What is your name?
Faiakes
Hello Faiakes
What is 8 + 8 ?
Answer here: 16
Well done
What is 6 - 6 ?
Answer here: 0
Well done
What is 2 / 5 ?
Answer here: 0.2
No
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None--------
The program does not pick the functions randomly, it simply executes all 3 of them and then goes through the loop

Comment: From what I can tell, the program cannot pick one item from the list (which here stands for a function). It executes the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ADD=Add()` calls `Add()` and sets `ADD` to the returned value, which is `None`.  Ditto for the next two lines. `Arith=[ADD,SUB,DIV]` sets `Arith` to `[None, None, None]`.  The direct answer to your question is to get rid of these four lines and change the loop to

```
for i in range(10):
    random.choice((Add, Sub, Div))()
```

This still has the problem that Div requires people to enter numbers like `0.2857142857142857` (on my machine) to be 'correct'.  Here is my version of your program.

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, floordiv
from random import choice

tries = 10
maxn = 9
numbers = list(range(1, maxn+1))
ops = (('+', add), ('-', sub), ('*', mul), ('//', floordiv))

for i in range(tries):
    left = choice(numbers)
    right = choice(numbers)
    op = choice(ops)
    print("What is", left, op[0], right,"?")
    try:
        user = int(input("Answer here: "))
    except ValueError:
        user = None
    if user == op[1](left, right):
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")
```

(Added in response to question about 'op') op is a tuple (pair) and op[n] selects one of the members of the tuple. The 3 lines containing 'op' could be replaced by the following, which might be clearer.

```
symbol, function = choise(ops)
...
    print("What is", left, symbol, right,"?")
    ...
    if user == function(left, right):
```

Comment: Thanks Terry.

  Hmmm, that might work for something else the program needs to do:  I need to keep a score of correct answers and produce a tally at the end.

Comment: If one or more of these answers solve your problem, please mark at least one as such.

Comment: I like your's better Terry.Thanks. I've also added the score and simplified it for my students (you are way more advanced than they are!)

Comment: Terry I understand all of the code except the --> op[0] and op[1]. Why are they like that?

Comment: Does added alternative code (currently in edit approval queue) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

[not really an answer, just a long, formatted comment]

```
 ADD = Add()
```

means "execute the function add and bind the name ADD to the object returned by the function" while you are probably thinking that  you were binding the name ADD to a function object.

please try this at the interpreter prompt

```
>>> def t3e(): return 3
>>> A = t3e()
>>> B = t3e    # NO PARENTHESES 
>>> print(A)
>>> print(B)
```

do you see a difference?

Next step, the list of functions.  At this point, I hope that you understand what is happening in your program, but try this

```
 >>> L1 = [ t3e(), t3e(), t3e()]
 >>> print(L1)
 [ 3, 3, 3]
 >>>
```

the list of functions Arith, as in your program, is not a list of functions, it's a list of returned values! NB: your functions Sum etc return None, so Arith is a list full of None's.

Now,

```
>>> L2 = [ t3e, t3e, t3e ] # NO parentheses!
>>> print(L2[0])
<function div at 0x7f640f2b8668>
>>> print(L2[0]())
3
```

Have you tried each step?  Do you understand now the difference between a function object (in pythonspeak, a *callable object*) and its invocation?  You have to store the *callables* in a container (here, a list), retrieve one element from the container (you use random.choice, here I have used indexing, but it's the same) and **you call the callable** using `()`.

```
>>> random.choice(L2)
<function t3e>
>>> random.choice(L2)()
3
```

Note that I chose to use in my example different names and semantics from your program for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and I will get back to you.

Comment: My time zone is, I think, different from yours. Quite different. See you later

Comment: I think I got it (see answer below)

Comment: Nope similar timezone and it is getting late...I'm off to sleep, too.

Answer (score 0):

@gboffi

I extended your example until it made sense to me and it worked:

---

```
import random

def t1e():
    return 1

def t2e():
    return 2

def t3e():
    return 3

def t4e():
    return 4

def t5e():
    return 5

L2 = [t1e,t2e,t3e,t4e,t5e]

print(random.choice(L2)())
```

---

Now here is the program (mostly) working:

---

```
import random
from random import shuffle

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
rand1=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand2=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand3=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand4=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand5=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
rand6=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)

def Add():
    print("What is", rand1,"+",rand2,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand1+rand2:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")


def Sub():
    print("What is", rand3,"-",rand4,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand3-rand4:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")


def Div():
    print("What is", rand5,"/",rand6,"?")
    user=float(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == float("{0:.1f}".format(rand5/rand6)):
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")       


name = input("Hi. What is your name?\n")
print("Hello",name)


Arith=[Add,Sub,Div]

x=1
while x<=10:
    print(random.choice(Arith)())
    x+=1
```

---

Comment: I see that luckily you've received more substantial help than mine! I hope that my example, while not a direct answer to your problem, may have been of help in the understanding of other people's answers.  In particular Terry's one is outstanding, study it carefully! good bye

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of things wrong with your script.

#### First,

The array of numbers is not really necessary

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
rand1=random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
```

can be replaced by

```
rand1=random.randint(0,9)
```

#### Second,

`rand1` ... `rand6` are generated at the start of the program, and they don't change when the same function is called twice. Even if your loop completed successfully, you would see the same question repeated with the exact same numbers.

To take care of this, I changed all the arithmetic functions to accept two arguments, `rand1`, `rand2`, and replaced each occurrence of `rand3`, `rand4`, `rand5` & `rand6` with `rand1` & `rand2` respectively.

#### Third,

You should put the functions that you need to call without the enclosing parenthesis in your list
i.e.
replace

```
ADD=Add()
SUB=Sub()
DIV=Div()


Arith=[ADD,SUB,DIV]
```

with

```
Arith=[Add, Sub, Div]
```

#### Finally,

Within the loop:

- a random function from `Arith` is fetched
- The random numbers `rand1` & `rand2` are generated
- the function is called with the two random numbers
- the counter is incremented by 1

### tl;dr: Here's my modified code

```
import random
from random import shuffle

def Add(rand1, rand2):
    print("What is", rand1,"+",rand2,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand1+rand2:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")

def Sub(rand1, rand2):
    print("What is", rand1,"-",rand2,"?")
    user=int(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == rand1-rand2:
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")

def Div(rand1, rand2):
    print("What is", rand1,"/",rand2,"?")
    user=float(input("Answer here: "))
    if user == float("{0:.1f}".format(rand1/rand2)):
        print("Well done")
    else:
        print("No")

Arith=[Add, Sub, Div]

name = input("Hi. What is your name?\n")
print("Hello",name)
x=1
while x<=10:
    f = random.choice(Arith)
    rand1 = random.randint(0, 9)
    rand2 = random.randint(0, 9)
    f(rand1, rand2)
    x += 1
```

Comment: You are very right indeed. Thanks Ali I have simplified it.However, this code doesn't stop after 10 tries.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i did not increment x in the loop. the last line of my code was missed while copying over the code, I edited the answer and it should terminate the loop after ten questions.